# "width=device-width" doesn't always work on fixed sized layout on mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a layout with fixed width, and it's viewport property is set to :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

So I expect the rendered page to fit the device width even if my fixed layout width is wider than the device's width.

I know about the `initial-scale=1` property but I don't need it since my layout isn't fluid.

My question is, why when page content's height isn't enough to scroll, width=device-width doesn't work on mobile safari :

[JSBIN Example 1](http://jsbin.com/pulopohalo)

... while it works when content's height is long enough that you have to scroll :

[JSBIN Example 2](http://jsbin.com/yovulafuwi)

PS : I know that putting width=my-fixed-width on both pages or even removing all viewport settings should resolve the problem. My question is why the above ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are strange things.
It seems that the rule "width > height" in action